# after upgrade wordpress jquery stop working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

after upgrade to new worpdress jquery stop working.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expr' of undefined
2
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Window] is not a function www.xxx.si:313
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Window] is not a function thickbox.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.form.min.js:12
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function scripts.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Window] is not a function 
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

details for example:

```
cannot read property 'expr' of undefined
```

jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {

```
undefined is not a function scripts.js:3
$(function() {
```

what is wrong? how can I solve this?

EDIT:

Mat help me to find this noConflict jquery which is part of event calendar plugin

```
// jQuery DOM extreme protection management
    $options = get_option('optionsEventsCalendar');
   echo ' <script type="text/javascript">',"\n\t";
   echo '// <![CDATA[',"\n\t";
   echo 'var ecd = {};',"\n\t";
   echo 'ecd.jq = jQuery.noConflict('.$options['jqueryextremstatus'].');',"\n\t";
   echo '//]]>',"\n";
   echo ' </script>',"\n";
    echo "<!-- End Of Script Generated By Events-Calendar - ".EVENTSCALENDARVERS." -->\n";
```

Comment: The errors you are getting suggest that jQuery isn't being included properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code on www.mdns-maribor.si uses [$.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var ecd = {};
ecd.jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
//]]>
</script>
```

This will remove the `jQuery` and `$` variables. You don't need jQuery.noConflict unless you want to override the `jQuery` and `$` values. If you do need it wait until the rest of the code has run before calling it.

Comment: where did you find that, becouse i can not find this in my code. so what can i do? if i remove this everything else will stop working i think.

Comment: Why would it? Have you tried removing it? At the moment your code depends on global `jQuery` and `$` variables, but your jQuery variable is called `ecd`. It seems like the other two variables were present before but didn't cause problems.

Comment: i found where this is stored. This is part of events calendar plugin. i update my question. Can i remove this code form plugin?

Comment: @mbrc It might be that the plugin requires a specific version of jQuery. In that case just load jQuery again. (Add a new `<script> `tag.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your upgrade somehow removed your include of the jQuery source code.

Check out the part of your solution where you include it.

The smoking gun is

> Property 'jQuery' of object [object Window] is not a function

Your code is calling jQuery, but JavaScript tells you that it is not defined.

Comment: I'd also point out , they may not be removed , but may be after the other js files , which will still throw exceptions